# PowerPoint Interop: copy-pasting a shape crashes if done too fast

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, .net-4.6.1, powerpoint-interop

I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` in a C#/.NET program in order to automate some operation on a PPTX file.

I'm trying to create a copy of an existing Shape in the presentation by using this code:

```
var shape = slide.Shapes[1];
shape.Copy();
var newShape = targetSlide.Shapes.Paste();
```

however, the `Paste()` instruction is unreliable, it sometimes works but sometimes (apparently at random) throws the following exception:

> ERROR: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80048240):
> Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Clipboard is empty or
> contains data which may not be pasted here.    in
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes.Paste()

After fiddling around for a bit and searching online, I found out that the problem is that the `.Copy()` instruction is apparently asynchronous, basically when it returns there is no guarantee that the shape object has actually been copied to the clipboard.
In fact, adding a:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

between the `Copy()` and `Paste()` instructions fixes the problem.

However, sleeping is not a proper solution, it slows down the program greatly and there is no way of knowing if you have set the sleep time too high or too low.

My question is: is there a more reliable way to wait for the copy to be "ready" before pasting?

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but here is my solution:
It happened to me when I was iterating over shapes in a slide. Copying each and pasting each sometimes throws the error you mentioned. What I did is that I copied the shapes all at once.

```
CurrentSelection.SlideRangle.Shapes.Copy();
targetPresentation.Slides[index].Shapes.Paste();
```

Another ideea would be to copy the whole slide:

```
CurrentSelection.SlideRangle.Shapes.Copy();
```

and then

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting");
```

you can also use "PasteDestinationTheme"